# google map gpx loading, how to?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

There are lots of gpx data out there.
using google map, Kml data loading and displaying is easy.
the code is:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml');
        ctaLayer.setMap(this.mMap);
```

but, I want to make a gpx data display on the google map.
I know I can use [babel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/), the converter, it's a software not library.

I have no idea what's the best way to display gpx data on google map.
making converter using php(duplicated file), or making loader using javascript... --;

my current programming language is php for server.

any good idea or comment please~~~

Answer (score 3):

You can feed GPX files to the KmlLayer constructor you have on your question. The code below worked for me:

```
function initialize() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73, -111.93);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://siteyoucontrol.com/lake-gpx.xml');

    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestions, both require some work on your side.  [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) is a javascript mapping API that includes a GPX reader, you could possibly use OpenLayers (with Google as a base map) or just use the GPX format reader.  Alternately, you could use the [OGR](https://web.archive.org/web/20190515223120/https://www.gdal.org/ogr/) library command line utility `ogr2ogr` to convert from GPX to KML, possibly setting up a web service to do so.  It would be easy to wrap the command line call in a PHP script that could retrieve a GPX file by URL and convert it into KML and return the resulting KML.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a very simple way to do this: perform an AJAX request to load the GPX file from Javascript, then parse it (very staightforward using jQuery) and create a polyline to display on the Google map.

More details and live example here: [Display GPX tracks using Google Maps API](http://www.jacquet80.eu/blog/post/2011/02/Display-GPX-tracks-using-Google-Maps-API) (works with Google Maps API v3).